# Handlebars access nested array values by specific index's value

Tags: html, node.js, json, handlebars.js

I know It may be asked before for how to access, What I want to know is how to get it in a certain pattern as I am new to Handlebars.

so I am having one `json` data as follows.

```
    "value": [
      {
        "tos": [
              {
                  "emailAddress": {
                      "name": "random random1",
                      "address": "random.r@random.com"
                  }
              },
              {
                  "emailAddress": {
                      "name": "abcd xyz",
                      "address": "abcd.x@radom.com"
                  }
              }
          ]
      },
      {
        "tos": [
              {
                  "emailAddress": {
                      "name": "random2 random2",
                      "address": "random2.r@random2.com"
                  }
              },
              {
                  "emailAddress": {
                      "name": "qwer zxc",
                      "address": "qwer.z@radom2.com"
                  }
              }
          ]
      }

   ]
```

What I want is to get that name & address in the following manner.
`name(emailAddress)`

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <th>Tos</th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>random random1(random.r@random.com)<br>
          abcd xyz(abcd.x@radom.com)
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>random2 random2(random2.r@random2.com)<br>
          qwer zxc(qwer.z@radom2.com)
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I have tried so far is...

```
<tr>
{{#each messages}}
 {{#each this.tos}}
  {{#each this.emailAddress}}
    <td>{{this.name}}({{this.address}})</td>
  {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</tr>
```

but I didn't have much luck and I have also tried...
`{{this.[1]}}` or `{{emailAddress.name}}` or `{{name}}`

So can anybody help me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would remove the `{{#each this.emailAddress}}` line from the template. This iterates over each property of each `emailAddress` Object - ie., `.name` and `.address`.

```
{{#each this.tos}}
    <td>
        {{this.emailAddress.name}}(this.emailAddress.address)}}
    <td>
{{/each}}
```

The above will output the data we want but will put each `emailAddress` in its own `<td>`. However, your expected output has all `emailAddress`es within each `tos` Array to be within a single `<td>` separated by a `<br>`. We can use Handlebars' [@last data variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#last) to conditionally render the `<br>` for each but the last item in the `tos` Array:

```
{{#each messages}}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{#each this.tos}}
                {{this.emailAddress.name}}({{this.emailAddress.address}})
                {{#if @last}}{{else}}<br>{{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Note that the `<td>` has to contain the `{{each this.tos}}` in order for the Objects within a `tos` to be rendered within a single `<td>`. Also, since we want a `<tr>` for each Object in `messages` we must move the `<tr>` to within the `{{#each messages}}` line.

I have created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/e1h2sync/15/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :D. yes, this works for me.